# QuickReport Salvar PDF por Padrao

Tags: delphi, quickreport

Meus relatórios sempre tem o componente TQRPDFfilter, para poderem ser exportado para PDF.
Contudo o cliente esta reclamando que ao clicar em salvar, ele ainda tem que selecionar o formato que deseja salvar(no caso, pdf), pois vem sempre como QRP.
Queria saber se tem um jeito no quickReport de eu definir a opção padrão, ou melhor ainda, remover a opção de salvar em QRP.  alguem sabe?

Answer (score 2):

Ressuscitando o tópico para futuras dúvidas:
Altere a propriedade `PreviewDefaultSaveType` do seu quickreport para `stPDF`.

Answer (score 1):

usava esse código no quickreport 3.0 e delphi 7,  acredito que ainda esteja funciona nas versões mais atuais.

```
   procedure ReportExport(aReport: TQuickRep; const aFileName: TFileName);
    var Pdf: TPdfDocument;
         aMeta: TMetaFile;
         i: integer;
    begin
      Pdf := TPdfDocument.Create;
      try
        aReport.Prepare;
        for i := 1 to aReport.QRPrinter.PageCount do begin
          aMeta := aReport.QRPrinter.GetPage(i);
          try
            Pdf.DefaultPageWidth := MulDiv(aMeta.Width,72,Pdf.ScreenLogPixels);
            Pdf.DefaultPageHeight := MulDiv(aMeta.Height,72,Pdf.ScreenLogPixels);
            Pdf.AddPage;
            // desenha a pagina
            Pdf.Canvas.RenderMetaFile(aMeta,1,0,0);
          finally
            aMeta.Free;
          end;
        end;
        Pdf.SaveToFile(aFileName);
      finally
        Pdf.free;
      end;
```

Assim ele vai exportar em pdf direto.

Comment: Isso é até interessante... apesar de não ser o que eu queria, talvez seja um contorno